# progruard to only obfuscate variable names?

Tags: proguard

I would like to use ProGuard to just rename variable and functions.  I want the resultant class files to be identical to the source jar in every regard except for the names.  Is there an option to do this?

My attempts at using `dontoptimize` and `dontshrink` are not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the following in your .pro file, and make sure that you don't use the "-keep" option to prevent other things from being obfuscated.

```
# Don't keep the local variables attributes (LocalVariableTable and LocalVariableTypeTable are dropped).
-keepattributes Exceptions,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,SourceDir,LineNumberTable,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,InnerClasses,*Annotation*
```

In other words, make sure that you don't have the following in your options

```
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
```